# Convert JavaRDD<Row> to JavaPairRDD<String,Map>

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I get an instance of `JavaRDD<Row>` (`ROW` from [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html)) which I want to convert to `JavaPairRDD<String,Map>`, because I want to join it with other rdd  afterwards. (**Inline somewhat off topic question**: Will it work? Specifically, will having `Map` as a second type parameter of `JavaPairRDD` result in correct merging of key-value pairs?)

When I do:

```
System.out.println(rdd.collect());
```

It prints in the following form:

```
[[{key1=val11,key2=val12,key3=val13,...}],[{key1=val21,key2=val22,key3=val23,...}],...,[{key1=val31,key2=val32,key3=val33,...}]]
```

Notice that the format is `[[{}],[{}],...[{}]]`. This is because, `rdd` contains list of `Row`s where each `Row` contains `UnfodifiableMap` (as explained below).
I want value of `key7` to be the key in `JavaPairRDD`. That is, I want following to be the final form of output:

```
{val17={key1=val11,key2=val12,key3=val13,...}, val27={key1=val21,key2=val22,key3=val23,...},..., val37={key1=val31,key2=val32,key3=val33,...}}
```

I started by observing the contents of `rdd` in debugging node inside dummy `foreach`:

[image]

Observing different values while in debug mode:

1. `JavaRDD` contains `GenericRowWithSchema`:
   [image]
2. `f.get(0)` returns map:
   [image]
3. I cannot access anything out of above map:
   [image]
4. Its (`f.get(0)`) is actually `UnmodifiableMap`:
   [image]

I am a bit surprised to have `GenericRowWithSchema` and `UnmodifiableMap`.  I continued by forming `JavaPairRDD` as follows:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Map> pairrdd = neo4jrdd.flatMapToPair(f -> { 
        return new Tuple2<String, Map>(f.getString(7),(Map)f.get(0));
});
```

But it is giving me:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from JavaPairRDD<Object,Object> to JavaPairRDD<String,Map>
```

I am not able to guess how can I get `JavaPairRDD` from `JavaRDD<Row>`. Where I am going wrong with above?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to do it as follows:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Map> pairRdd = rdd.mapToPair(f -> {
        return new Tuple2<String, Map>(((Map)f.get(0)).get("id").toString(), ((Map)f.get(0)));
    });
```

`f.get(0).get("id")` above corresponds to `f.getString(7)`, that is I misunderstood how do I access cell values in `Row`. In fact I still dont get it fully. The [`Row` API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html) states I should be using `getString()`, but it is not working. Can someone explain why?

Also there is no need of `flatMapToPair()`. I am able to do it with `mapToPair()`.